# Теряются письма при отправке через php

Tags: php, smtp, gmail

Отправляю html письмо стандартным методом через php.

```
$subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($subject);
$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Precedence: bulk\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$from."\r\n";
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Настроен postfix для домена через gmail. Проблема в том что некоторые письма отправляются нормально, некоторые нет. Если зайти в почту отправителя на gmail, то там письмо отправленное есть. А до адресата оно не доходит
В отправленных

```
Исходное сообщение
Идентификатор сообщения <20190205143245.A773DC80D68@mail.mydomain.com>
Создано:    5 февраля 2019 г., 15:32 (доставлено через 1 секунду)
От: Robot <robot@mydomain.com>
Кому:   mymail@gmail.com
Тема:   Тестовое письмо!
```

В логе:

```
Feb  5 15:32:46 sip postfix/smtp[9458]: A773DC80D68: to=<mymail@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.184.26]:25, delay=0.56, delays=0.1/0.01/0.2/0.25, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1549377166 z1si5826796wrv.117 - gsmtp)
```

Comment: Как-то года полтора назад на шаред хостинге была похожая фигня и когда задал вопрос хостеру мне сказали что они рандомно попадают под фильтры гугла. После натсроил phpmailer и больше не было такой проблемы

Comment: Ясно, давно собирался на него перейти. Видимо пора ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все-таки phpmailer исправил проблему и письма больше не исчезают